# Asterisk character in password - login failed

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sftp

I have a requirement where i will do sftp to a different server and i want to do  this by a shell script

But the password is having asterisk(*) character, so unable to log in.
Script :

```
host=xxxxx
user=celcom_mnp
passwd='CjX3E$4Q&*B6L'
cd /home/mquser/unicaftp/CMS/batch/OBD/MNP/
test=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.csv" -mmin +1 | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
lftp<<EOF
open sftp://$host
user  $user $passwd
cd /MNP_Autoin
lcd  /home/mquser/unicaftp/CMS/batch/OBD/MNP
mput `echo $test`
EOF
OUT=$?
if [ $OUT -eq 0 ];then
   echo "$test Succesfully transferred" >> /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/OBD/obdmnplog.txt
else
   echo "Issue with sftp" >> /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CEP/PUSH/sftplog.txt
fi
mv $test /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/OBD/TEMPMNP/
```

Error info :

```
Unknown command `*B6L'.
cd: Login failed: Login incorrect
```

Please help me out.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your script to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus : Added complete script.  Thanks

Comment: @Cyrus : I am unable to login with the password above may be because of special characters in the password.  You can refer to the error info which i provided above.  thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `&` (ampersand). Replace

```
user  $user $passwd
```

with

```
user  $user "$passwd"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using double quotes instead of quotes.
Or if you know your password will always be that specific text, you can escape the special characters $ & * by preceding them with a backslash.

There are a few different solution you can try from google:
[Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell)

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply.  Same error even if i try with double quotes.

Comment: Can you escape them by preceding them with a \?  
Sometime I have also had success by using a ' and a "
"'asdf&*$asdf'"

Comment: It works if in this case only & is escaped by a backslash in this way: `passwd='CjX3E$4Q\&*B6L'`.